# How to change priority of network connection without admin right?

Tags: windows-7, networking, bindings

I'm using Window 7, but would like to change the priority order of network connection (Change Network Adapter Bindings). It was under Control panel --> Network and internet --> Advanced Setting --> Adapters and Bindings. But I have no admin right....need help from experts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you the administrator of this computer? If not, then you have to contact the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's an administrator function.